# jQuery change the value of the name attribute in .each() working in console.log but not page source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the name attribute of a cloned table row.
Here is my code:

```
    var ipCount = 2;
$("#input_form").on("click", "#add_input_param", function() {
    $('#input_param tr').eq(1).clone().find('input').val('').end()
            .appendTo('#input_param > thead')
            .find('*[name]')
            .each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
        $(this).attr('name', 'new_name');
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    ipCount++;
});
```

on the console it changed the name attr to new_name but not showing when I do Inspect Element on Chrome DevTools.
This is the console:

```
    :ops1/6/1/1_param js.js:48
    new_name js.js:50
    :ops1/6/1/1_type js.js:48
    new_name js.js:50
    :ops1/6/1/1_required js.js:48
    new_name js.js:50
    :ops1/6/1/1_desc js.js:48
    new_name js.js:50
    :ops1/6/1/1_location js.js:48
    new_name
```

HTML after click shows on DevTools:

```
    <input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_param" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

I been trying to interate the name attribute but it doesn't seem to change when I do it.

My HTML table( the row was cloned from a cloned table) it might be the reason why it's not changing the name attr)

```
    <h4>
                        3.3.5 Input Parameters
                    </h4>
                    <table id="input_param" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Parameter</th>
                                <th>Data Type</th>
                                <th>Required</th>
                                <th>Brief description</th>
                                <th>Location in Request</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_param" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_type" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="required" name=":ops1/6/1/1_required">
                                        <option value="Mandatory" >Mandatory</option>
                                        <option value="Optional" >Optional</option>
                                        <option value="Conditional" >Conditional</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><textarea name=":ops1/6/1/1_desc"></textarea></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name=":ops1/6/1/1_location">
                                        <option value="Header" >Header</option>
                                        <option value="Body" >Body</option>
                                        <option value="Query_param" >Query Parameter</option>
                                        <option value="Resource_uri" >Resource URI</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>     
                    <input type="button" id="add_input_param" value="+ Add Input Parameter" data-inline="true" /><br />
```

Comment: when you say `page source`, do you mean what you see when you **View Source**? That code never changes. You're only having a problem if you try to **Inspect Element** and don't see the changes there.

Comment: yes, Inspect Element is what I did, sorry for the confusion. I will repharase my question.

Comment: Show your HTML, please. Also, a jsFiddle would help.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, you are cloning the element, so the original one is not changed, but your new nodes would have the modified name.

Comment: @MasterAM I did the Inspect Element on Chrome DevTools, the new cloned nodes are not modified either.

Comment: @PHPglue I just post my HTML, also the row I am trying to modifed the name attribte was cloned from a cloned table. I think that might be the reason but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Why would you append the second element in a `<tr>` to the `<thead>`, after assigning any `<input value=''>`? That seems odd.

Comment: Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/zasak/). It is a bit simplified, but the clones do have the new name.

Comment: @PHPglue It works after I changed it to " .appendTo('#input_param > tbody')" Thanks for point that out!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr').appendTo('#foo').find('.bar')
```

doesn't find elements in '#foo' element, it will find elements that has classed '.bar' inside of 'table tr'. So, your chain is not that you want. You can write like that:

```
var ipCount = 2;
$("#input_form").on("click", "#add_input_param", function() {
    $('#input_param tr').eq(1).clone().find('input').val('').end()
            .appendTo('#input_param > thead')
            .find('#input_param > thead [name]')
            .each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name', 'new_name');
            });
    ipCount++;
});
```

Comment: Still not working....the name attributes still remain the same.
It actually found the element though because when I output console .attr('name') it shows, I just not able to modify it. any idea what might be the cause of it?

Comment: When you console it, you probably printing names of inputs that inside of '#input_param tr'. If you can give an example in jsfiddle or codepen etc, we can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_param" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

would be `.eq(0)`, and what @Murat Çorlu said.

Comment: .eq(0) would be just the header of my table though. I got it works after changing .appendTo('#input_param > tbody'). Thank you!